# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space with Collision Detection

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory, collision, paint

I was trying to do a collision detection and managed to do it in fact however its throwing a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space, I believe its because constantly checking where the xPosition and yPosition is

```
    public void fireBullet(Graphics g, int pow, int angle, int size) {
    Rectangle bullet = new Rectangle(xPos - size/2, yPos - size/2, size, size);
    g.setColor(new Color(200,255,255));
    g.fillOval(bullet.x, bullet.y, bullet.width, bullet.height);    
    if (LevelType.EASY != null & bullet.intersects(Level1.getBoundsR())){
    System.out.println("hi from level 1");
    xPosition = 50;
    yPosition = 350;
    this.setFocusable(false);
    new Something().setVisible(true);
        }
```

and right after this class in PaintComponent I have

```
fireBullet(g, xPosition, yPosition, 10);
```

I have also set VM argument to -Xms512M -Xmx2048M, and watched on the task manager how quickly my memory was going, I'd say it was gone in about 30 seconds.

FOLLOW UP

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.awt.image.DataBufferByte.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.image.ComponentSampleModel.createDataBuffer(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.image.Raster.createWritableRaster(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createBufferedImage(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageReader.getDestination(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.read(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at cannonGame.GamePanel.paintComponent(GamePanel.java:99)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

plus I have commented out the collision detection code and you guys were right, it was not it.

ANOTHER FOLLOWUP
So I have checked what is at the GamePanel.java:99 and found this code that I wasnt really using, it was just there, I removed it and now everything is smooth.

```
    BufferedImage myPicture = null;
    try {
        myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/Level1Bk.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
    add(picLabel);
```

So as @Oleg Estekhin mentioned a new picture is being painted with each repaint, thank yuou

Comment: Are you sure it's this method that cause the OutOfMemory? How many times is this method called? What about `Level1.getBoundsR()` ? And the `new Color(200,255,255)` this could be declared as static.

Comment: I can not see anything here that is being added to the heap that can not subsequently be gc'd.  Maybe post your stacktrace.

Comment: If you're getting OOM exceptions it's because you're using too much memory.  If you're not intentionally creating gigantic arrays then consider whether you might be creating a "chain" of "abandoned" objects with each pointing to the next, and the most recently abandoned object pointed to from some in-use object.

Comment: May be you might have done it any how, did you restart eclipse/System after changing the heap size. Try to load with other eclipse just make sure your eclipse is working fine after the changes

Comment: Note that where you blow up on an OOM is not likely to be where the "bad" code is -- the code at the time of the failure is just unlucky enough to have asked for heap when it was all gone.

Comment: The stacktrace shows that you are loading some png file anew on *each* repaint. Change your code to load all resources once.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin I think you must put your comment as an answer.

Comment: I agree, I do want to thank him some other way than just writing it.